# why my button doesnt work in this html file?? can anyone find what is the error of the code

Tags: html

I have problem with my student buttons inside this html file..can anyone help me? i take this code from the internet. when i click the button, it doesnt redirect me to the login.php..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <title>Supervision System</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen Background Image Slideshow with CSS3 - A Css-only fullscreen background image slideshow" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="css3, css-only, fullscreen, background, slideshow, image, content" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="page">
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>SUPERVISION SYSTEM</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>SUPERVISION SYSTEM</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>SUPERVISION SYSTEM</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3>SUPERVISION SYSTEM</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3>SUPERVISION SYSTEM</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3>SUPERVISION SYSTEM</h3></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
           <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <div class="codrops-top">

                <div class="clr"></div>
             </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
            <header>
                 <p class="codrops-demos">
                    <a href="">Coordinator</a>
                    <a href="">Supervisor</a>
                    <a href="localhost:8080/fyp/login.php">Student</a>//-----right here the problem
                </p>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this on a web server on port 8080? Is your `login.php` file inside a directory called `fyp`, which is located at the server root?

Answer (score 1):

That's a link, not a button. It should just fine, so long as you intended to write a relative URL.

It looks like you intended to write an absolute URL though and you forgot to include `http://` or `https://` at the front of it (or possibly `//` if you wanted a scheme relative URL, which is unlikely since you included a port number).

Comment: owh..okay its a link..my bad..i said it button because the interface looks exactly like a button..thank you for your respond..already settled

Answer (score 0):

```
            <a href="http://localhost:8080/fyp/login.php">Student</a>//-----right here the problem
```

Should work. You forgot the `http://`